# GitHub version control on FTP based website?

Tags: php, svn, github, version

I am currently interacting with my sites via `FTP`, which can get quite annoying and impossible to manage at times.

Is it possible to use `GitHub` as a version control system for my `PHP` based websites which is on a different domain name?

If not, can anyone give me some advice on what tool I should look into using in order to set up version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, found the solution to my question.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/how-to-use-git-with-ftp/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `git` repository with all of your code for your website, and host it on `Github`.  Then you can make changes, commit them to your local repository, and push them to `Github`.  Afterwards, when you want to deploy your changes, do a `git pull` on your `Github` repository from the remote server.

`Git` is a distributed version control system.  You have local repositories sitting in your local machine (your laptop, desktop, etc.)  `Github` is a remote repository hosting service (sort of like Dropbox).  When you want to sync the repo in your computer with the one hosted by `Github`, you do a pull/push.  Then, you can sync the repository hosted by `Github` with the thrid repository on the server that hosts your website using a push/pull.  No `ftp` is needed.

Comment: When you say `commit them to your local repository` do you mean upload them via `ftp` to my server, then do a **separate** `commit/push` to `github`? OR will `committing/pushing` to `git`, will auto move the changes to my `FTP` site?

Comment: There are 3 repos: one on your desktop, one hosted by `Github`, and a third on the server that hosts your website.  You can develop your site locally, and commit your changes to your local repo.  When you want to deploy, you can sync your repo with the one in `Github`, and then sync the one in `Github` with the one in the server that hosts your website.

Comment: That's not very convenient.

Comment: Really?  All you have to do is commit your changes to your local repo, and type in `git push`.  Then on your remote server and type in `git pull`.

Comment: I agree with him. It sounds simple but can get very complicated and buggy.